# How to use Pivottabler on concatenated strings in R

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this-

```
LDAutGroup  PatientDays ExposedDays sex    Ageband    DrugGroup Prop    LowerCI UpperCI concat
Group1            100        23       M    5 to 10      PSY      23       15.84   32.15  23 (15.84 -32.15)    F
Group2            500        56       F    11  to 17    HYP      11.2      8.73   14.27  11.2 (8.73 -14.27)
Group3            300        89       M    18 and over  PSY      29.67    24.78   35.07  29.67 (24.78 -35.07)
Group1            200        34       F    5 to 10      PSY      17       12.43   22.82  17 (12.43 -22.82)
Group2            456        78       M    11 to 17     ANX      17.11    13.93   20.83  17.11 (13.93 -20.83)
```

Following this, I want a pivot table to lay out the concat column as the valuename. However, the pivottabler only works on integers or numeric values. The following code runs right with either of the Prop, LowerCI or UpperCI columns on their own, but gives an error message for the concat column-

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(epitools)
library(gtools)
library(reshape2)
library(binom)
library(pivottabler)    
pt <- PivotTable$new()
    pt$addData(a)
    pt$addColumnDataGroups("LDAutGroup")
    pt$addColumnDataGroups("sex")
    pt$addRowDataGroups("DrugGroup")
    pt$addRowDataGroups("Ageband")
    pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="TotalTrains", type="value", valueName="Prop")
    pt$renderPivot()
```

Is there a way I can make this work on the concat column? I want a table that has the following layout and the cells populated with the strings in concat column in the table above

```
                     Group1     Group2      Group3  
                      M   F     M    F      M    F
ANX 11 to 17                        
    18 and over                     
    Total                       
HYP 11  to 17                       
    18 and over                     
    5 to 10                     
    Total                       
PSY 18 and over                     
    5 to 10                     
    Total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the pivottabler package author.

As you say, pivottabler currently only pivots integer/numerical columns.  A workaround exists however, using a custom cell calculation function to calculate the value in each cell.  Custom calculation functions were intended for more complex use cases, so using them in this way is a sledgehammer approach, but it does the job, and I suppose makes sense in some scenarios, e.g. if you have other numerical pivot tables and want a uniform appearance for the pivot tables in your output.

Adapting an example from the package vignettes:

```
library(pivottabler)
library(dplyr)

trainsConcatendated <- mutate(bhmtrains, ConcatValue = paste(TOC, TrainCategory, sep=" "))

getConcatenatedValue <- function(pivotCalculator, netFilters, format, baseValues, cell) {
  # get the data frame
  trains <- pivotCalculator$getDataFrame("trainsConcatendated")
  # apply the filters coming from the headers in the pivot table
  filteredTrains <- pivotCalculator$getFilteredDataFrame(trains, netFilters)
  # get the distinct values
  distinctValues <- distinct(filteredTrains, ConcatValue)
  # get the value of the concatenated column
  # this just returns the first concatenated value for the cell
  # if there are multiple values, the others are ignored
  if(length(distinctValues$ConcatValue)==0) { tv <- "" }
  else { tv <- distinctValues$ConcatValue[1] }
  # build the return value
  # the raw value must be numerical, so simply set this to zero
  value <- list()
  value$rawValue <- 0
  value$formattedValue <- tv
  return(value)
}

pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(trainsConcatendated)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("TrainCategory", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$addRowDataGroups("TOC", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="ConcatValue", 
                     type="function", calculationFunction=getConcatenatedValue)
pt$renderPivot()
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is speculative to apply the same function for CI (lower or upper) as it could be for mean statistics to report subtotal levels, as well as no sense for concat to report subtotals (at least in the simple way of pivot table). 
With no subtotal you can easily use tidyr library and report variable with character type in spread format of table : here is 2 line code. First is create groups for columns and second line is to change table format to spread version

```
library(tidyr)

Table_Original <- unite(Table_Original, "Col_pivot", c("LDAutGroup", "sex"), sep = "_", remove = F)
Table_Pivot <- spread(Table_Original[ ,c("Col_pivot","DrugGroup", "Ageband", "concat")], Col_pivot, concat)
```

Comment: Thank you. But not quite what I am after- I need the sub rows in all the three groups by sex and also the DrugGroup to appear only once across all the age bands.